# What triggers GET handler for websockets connection in Go / Fiber?

Tags: go, go-fiber

For WebSockets support in Golang, many examples feature Fiber servers with endpoints like this:

```
    app.Use("/ws", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // IsWebSocketUpgrade returns true if the client
        // requested upgrade to the WebSocket protocol.
        if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
            return c.Next()
        }
        return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
    })
    // Websocket handler
    app.Get("/ws/:id", websocket.New(func(ws *websocket.Conn) {
        handler.MediaStreamHandler(ws)
    }))
```

The `app.Use` endpoint here is well-documented:  it initiates the WebSockets handshake and upgrades the connection protocol from HTTP to WebSockets.

Less clear is the `app.Get` endpoint.  I understand the idiomatic point:  it's where the receipt of real-time messaging over WebSockets takes place.  But what is not clear is who calls `app.Get`, and how is the WebSockets interface persisted across invocations of `app.Use` and `app.Get`?

I am guessing state attached to the WebSockets interface is persisted in the Fiber `app`.
But how is `app.Get` called?  Is the WebSockets client expected to make a request to `app.Get` so the Fiber server is cued to begin receipt of real-time messaging?

Answer (score 1):

app.Use registers a middleware, not a handler. So there really is no *endpoint* under /ws. The server as shown in the question would respond with status 404 for requests to /ws. The first argument simply limits the middleware to requests that have the given path prefix. [From the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber#App.Use):

> Use registers a middleware route. Middleware matches requests beginning with the provided prefix. Providing a prefix is optional, it defaults to "/".

With this setup, clients are expected to initiate websocket connections with something like `GET /ws/123 HTTP/1.1`. Because this path starts with /ws, the websocket middleware runs before the handler registered with `app.Get("/ws/:id", ...)`.

s.Next() in the middleware effectively calls the handler passed to app.Get.

Comment: so if I have a URL like `http://chat.acme.ai:80/ws/123`, and initiate an HTTP GET request to that URL, then the Fiber service should upgrade the socket to a WebSockets interface.  But in that case, what does my client logic look like?  IE, my client starts as an HTTP client making a GET call ... but how does that morph into a WebSockets client?